# Laravel join table validation

Tags: laravel, join

I want to validate join table. I only validated one table but what if I have a joined table. Based on the image attached. How can I validate it?

```
    public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);


    if ($validation->passes()){
        User::create($input);
        return View::make('users.create');
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.create')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validation)
                ->with('message', 'Please correct the following errors:');

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use many validators and also validate `UserAccount` model:

```
public function store()
{
    $input = Input::all();
    $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);

    $validation2 = Validator::make($input, UserAccount::$rules);


   $result = true;

   if (!$validation->passes()) {
      $result = false;
   }
   if (!$validation2->passes()) {
      $result = false;
   }

    if ($result) {
        User::create($input);
        return View::make('users.create');
    }
    return Redirect::route('users.create')
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors([$validation, $validation2])
                ->with('message', 'Please correct the following errors:');

}
```